# Canvas displaying weird

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a javascript program that utilizes a canvas to display some rectangles on the screen. When I run this on my ChromeBook (saving the file to Google Drive and downloading it) I get a space between some of the squares:
[image]

However, when I run this on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbgfLade/1/):

[image]

Here is the javascript section:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-50;
var charh = charw = 80;
function drawRect(x, y, height, width, color){
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    ctx.fill();
}
function Archer(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.draw = function (){
        updatePlayer(this.x+10, this.y, '#3B1000');
        updatePlayer(this.x+15, this.y, '#3B1000');
        updatePlayer(this.x+20, this.y, '#3B1000');
        updatePlayer(this.x+5, this.y+5, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+10, this.y+5, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+15, this.y+5, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+20, this.y+5, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+25, this.y+5, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+5, this.y+10, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+15, this.y+10, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+25, this.y+10, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+5, this.y+15, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+10, this.y+15, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+15, this.y+15, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+20, this.y+15, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+25, this.y+15, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+15, this.y+20, '#A56122');
        updatePlayer(this.x+10, this.y+10, '#FFFFFF');
        updatePlayer(this.x+20, this.y+10, '#FFFFFF');
    }
}
var myarcher = new Archer(canvas.width/2-charw/2, canvas.height/2-charh/2);
function update() {                
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    myarcher.draw();
    setTimeout(update, 10);
}
function updatePlayer(x, y, color){
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
    ctx.fill();
}
update();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines are caused by drawing on non-integer pixel boundaries. You can resize the browser by 1 pixel either horizontally or vertically to see the lines appear or disappear based on whether or not the height/width is even or odd.

Try this instead:

```
var myarcher = new Archer(Math.round(canvas.width/2-charw/2), Math.round(canvas.height/2-charh/2));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Might give you a bounty because you deserve it :D